# Failed to open inline XBRL Viewer link in WKWebView

Tags: swift, uiwebview, wkwebview, ios12, xbrl

I am trying to open link in WKWebView. But it fails. Error message: `Incompatible browser`. Its an inline XBRL Viewer.

Here's my code:

```
var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // 1
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/769397/000076939718000011/adsk-0131201810xk.htm")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
```

[image: Here's error details]
Same link opens up in mobile Safari and Mac safari. Can i support or handle such type of links in `WKWebView` or `UIWebView`?